# How do you only label factors in a barplot that have values above a certain value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dummy dataset like so:

```
factor<-c("A", "B", "C", "D")
count<-c(5, 10, 15, 20)
df<-cbind.data.frame(factor, count)
```

On the x axis tickmarks, I **only** want to label those factors that have count values greater than 10. I.E., only C and D will be labelled with their corresponding factor name.

This is the ggplot code I currently have right now:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=count, x=factor, fill=factor)+
geom_bar(stat="identity", show.legend=FALSE)+
ggtitle("title")+
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
         axis.text.x=element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

The theme call was my attempt at removing all labels, but I can't figure out a way to put those specific aforementioned factor labels back in.

Comment: You could leave the text and ticks and instead set the `breaks` based on your conditions but not sure if there is a way to avoid referring to the dataset directly like this: `+ scale_x_discrete(breaks = df$factor[df$count > 10])`

Comment: This is a friendly reminder that `geom_col()` is the same as `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate label column, something like the following:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(label = ifelse(count >= 10, count, NA))
```

Then you can use the `geom_label()` command to label the factors you want.